# Mapping Exception on symlinked vendor package

Tags: php, symfony, mapping, fosuserbundle, autoload

I got symfony3 application that uses 2 of my other symfony packages that I want to modify on the run without commiting, pushing and updating composer over and over.

I've downloaded them by `composer install` so the structure looks like

```
app/vendor/
|
+--company/
   |
   +--bundle1
   |
   +--bundle2
```

Everything worked perfect.

Than I downloaded repositories and put on the same level as my main project so I have:

```
projects/
|
+---app/
|
+---bundle1/
|
+---bundle2/
```

When I tried to symlink it to the vendor folder

```
cd project/app/vendor/company
rm -rf bundle1
ln -s project/bundle1 bundle1
```

Symfony gave me following **error**:

```
MappingException in MappingException.php line 96:
Class 'Company\Bundle1\Entity\User' does not exist
```

THe problem occurs because of FOSUserBundle configuration

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:              orm # Required
    firewall_name:          main # Required
    user_class:             Company\Bundle1\Entity\User # Required
```

Using Symfony3
I tried to do composer dump-autoload with no success - same error.

Looked over theese topics (and more here on stack):

http://www.askjong.com/howto/use-local-repository-with-composer
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1299

My Apache2.4 server configuration has "FollowSymLinks" option added.
Namespace are ok - it works when it is installed normally.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one thing to remember - if you have such strange problem - it has to do something with:

1. cache
2. configuration
3. file permissions

In my case it was permissions - my linked bundle1 `Entity` directory did not have right to execute.

```
chmod +x -R ./Entity
```

solved the problem,
silly me